# Nifi compare two flowfiles and if condition match allow another flowfile to success or failure

Tags: apache-nifi

Trying to allow a flowfile (containing csv values) success output to `PutEmail` processor only if a content from another flowfile (output of selectHive3QL) matches with attribute of another flowfile (output of FetchS3Object).

Between TaskConsolidator and NotifyDL need the comparison done:
[image]

based on the comparison between these two processors outputs:
[image]
1> totalrecords is content from hiveQL output:

[image]

2> totalrecords is attribute captured from another flowfile.
[image]

How does one achieve this action? If there is a better way to handle the decision, open to learn as well. This is at the end of series of operations being done to load hive table and at the end , trying to check a manifest file received from external source and check counts against hive table before marking it as success ( notify DL)

Any help would be great!

Comment: If this is all one big connected flow I suggest split the manifest part out from it. Have a processor monitor for the delivery of the manifest file. Once it arrives then get it, read the count from the DB and do the comparison at that point to determine if you are to send the email. If all the files come in at the same time to be processed then once all records have been processed and put into the DB then move the manifest to a folder or https it so another input will pick it up then process it.

Comment: `taskConsolidator` is generating a report at the final step. I need to retain the content for email body. I like the idea of writing the manifest file elsewhere and using another processor to pick up the value inside as attribute, any idea how to  trigger the action to do these series of operation( check Hive Count + compare Attribute from manifest file + keep report content before NotifyDL) ? I am assuming these actions need to be done in series and at end, otherwise have to match actions for two disparate flowfiles if flowfile comping from elsewhere